# Why question about tax rate for top 1% deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/49672/37236) was posted asking whether it's true that high income people don't pay much less in taxes than they did in the 1950s.  The question was very poorly worded, and did not link to a source, but it seemed like a legitimate question, with a notable claim, that could have been fixed and answered.

Curious why it was deleted so quickly without an opportunity to fix it.

Comment: archive.org unfortunately does not track this site. The question is irretrievably gone except for those with sufficiently high reputation points. That said, I can imagine who the pest in question would be. I don't think a one year cooling off period is enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question would be perfectly fine, so long as notability and being fleshed out a bit was improved.

The problem in this instance was the user. Verified by a few methods only available to moderators, it was determined that that particular account is in use by a troll that we've been trying to squish for years. The MO is apparently to create flame wars. All interaction with this user will ultimately prove fruitless.

If any legitimate user would like to ask the same question, it would be perfectly fine.

Comment: FYI, this person is a *network wide pest*. It's not a Skeptics SE problem only.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @LangLangC "MO" = *modus operandi*, i.e. how they go about their business.